# Need help identifying Chrome extension icons in toolbar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm trying to diagnose a problem in a website I work on and a co-worker I have no contact with any more was sent a screenshot with these extension icons in the toolbar:

[image: Chrome extensions in toolbar]

I recognise the jigsaws as broken extensions, the stop sign as Adblock, the elephant as Evernote and the rectangle as Chromecast.

Comment: Ask the user what extensions he has installed.

Comment: Yes, normally a good idea, but to be more accurate with the communication chain, it was sent to a co-worker who no longer works with us.

Comment: Are you able to right click on the extension? There's usually a link back to the Chrome Store listing. Or, are you working from the screenshot?

Comment: Unfortunately, just the screenshot.

Comment: @MarkHewitt Ah, this one is going to be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the one's you've identified, the check mark and the printer icon are,

- [Google Tasks (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-tasks-by-google/dmglolhoplikcoamfgjgammjbgchgjdd)
- [Print Friendly & PDF](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/print-friendly-pdf/ohlencieiipommannpdfcmfdpjjmeolj)

Perhaps someone else can identify the extension with the notifications and the other that looks like some privacy related thing.